# How to chain jax-rs base64 encoder and gzip

Tags: rest, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I would like to chain a base64 encoder and gzip in jax-rs via interceptors.

The encoder is implemented as follows:

```
@EncryptPayload
@Provider
@Priority(Priorities.ENTITY_CODER)
public class EncryptPayloadInterceptor implements WriterInterceptor {
    private Logger logger;

    @Inject
    public EncryptPayloadInterceptor(Logger logger) {
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    public EncryptPayloadInterceptor() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void aroundWriteTo(WriterInterceptorContext writerInterceptorContext) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
         logger.error("Calling EncryptPayload Interceptor: ");

        final OutputStream outputStream = writerInterceptorContext.getOutputStream();
        writerInterceptorContext.getHeaders().putSingle("X-ENCRYPTED", "true");
        writerInterceptorContext.setOutputStream(new Base64OutputStream((outputStream)));

        writerInterceptorContext.proceed();
    }
}
```

The gzip part is implemented as follows:

```
@Provider
@Priority(Priorities.USER)
public class GZIPWriterInterceptor implements WriterInterceptor {
    private Logger logger;

    @Inject
    public GZIPWriterInterceptor(Logger logger) {
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    public GZIPWriterInterceptor() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void aroundWriteTo(WriterInterceptorContext writerInterceptorContext) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
        logger.error("Calling GZIPWriter Interceptor: ");
        final OutputStream outputStream = writerInterceptorContext.getOutputStream();
        writerInterceptorContext.setOutputStream(new GZIPOutputStream(outputStream));
        writerInterceptorContext.getHeaders().putSingle("Content-Encoding", "gzip");

       writerInterceptorContext.proceed();
    }
}
```

When disabling gzip as a provider it works nicely. When enabling the provider GZIP I receive the following error within jersey:

```
LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, LocalizationMessages.ERROR_COMMITTING_OUTPUT_STREAM(), e);
```

First the encoding is called and after that the gzip is called. It seems that Base64 might close the stream.

Any help highly appreciated.

Comment: Solved as jersey already zips content if the headers are set. Therefore I deleted the interceptors